# undefined reference to `sleep'

Tags: gcc, include, sleep, linker-errors, mingw32

I just installed Codeblocks on my new PC,
now I'm trying to get a library running called CML(its a library from school and it's not very good) but I'm getting a strange error when i try to run some very basic example code.
its not the code itself in Devcpp it compiles just fine.

The Error:

`d:\program files\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libcml.a(video.o):video.c|| undefined reference to sleep'|`

Does anyone know how i can fix this?

Comment: Could you post a small example of code causing the error?

Comment: MinGW (or rather Windows) does not have a function `sleep`, only `Sleep`. Typo?

Comment: no i dont even use sleep.

Comment: And i'm sure its not the code because in devcpp it compiles just fine

Comment: I just looked in the `<unistd.h>` that comes with my MinGW (4.7.2). It has a prototype for `usleep` (presumably wraps `Sleep`) but not `sleep`. Makes me wonder how they compiled that library in the first place...

Comment: Well, I guess a workaround would be to put `void sleep(unsigned int sec) { Sleep(1000*sec); }` into your `main.c`. Not pretty, but should work...

Answer (score 0):

Damon is right the WinAPI only provides a function called Sleep. The error looks like the linker can't find this symbol in the libraries you are linking to.

A first guess would be that you have to add

```
-lWinmm
```

to your linker command line. However, as far as I recall the Devcpp IDE should add this library by default...

Comment: That would be `-lkernel32`, not `-lwinmm` (and yes, this is default), but still this won't solve the issue of `sleep` and `Sleep` being different symbols.

Comment: -lWinmm did not do the trick but i know that devcpp uses mingw 3.4.2 and CodeBlocks uses 4.7.2 maybe thats the problem?